# python parse json file from matlab

Tags: python, json, matlab, parsing

Friend!!
I'm working to convert Matlab code to python.

I have a problem when dealing with file I/O.

I'm trying to parse a json file which has been produced by the Matlab json library JSONLab. In this case, JSONLab outputs a binary string in the UBJSON format (see http://ubjson.org)

I'm using the json module in the python library to parse the file.

When I run the code below:

```
with open('raw.isd',encoding='utf-8') as f:
   recodes = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
```

it gives me the error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
>   171: invalid start byte

Then I try:

```
with codecs.open('raw.isd','r',encoding='utf8',errors='ignore') as f:
     recodes = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
```

but it returns

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in
>   double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

This file can be decoded by the Matlab json library.

Thank you for your help

Comment: could you [edit] your post to show a small representative `raw.isd` file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install an helper python package, for example:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-ubjson
to make your life a bit easier.
Notice that py-ubjson plus another package for Python are listed in the UBJSON website http://ubjson.org/libraries/